# setting up private eos blockchain cant connect to port 8888

Tags: nodeos

I am trying to setup private eos blockchain using https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence#section-1-create-configure-and-start-the-genesis-node

on step 1.7 when issue cleos create account eosio eosio.bpay i get error

console log of executing

```
najam@hpvm1:~/biosboot/genesis$ ./genesis_start.sh 



najam@hpvm1:~/biosboot/genesis$ cleos create account eosio eosio.bpay EOS7s7TxBxXFijJ│     ] Blockchain started; head block is #1, genesis timestamp is 2018-06-01T12:00:00.
3C2fB6ZgLumQry5jH9Z1FiDuFu6x7AHiAWt5y5                                               │000
Failed to connect to nodeos at http://127.0.0.1:8888/; is nodeos running?

najam@hpvm1:~/biosboot/genesis$ ./genesis_start.sh                                                                                                                                                                                    [1/113]
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.495 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:556          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin                                                                                                                       
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.498 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'RAM_RESTRICTIONS' (with digest of '4e7bf348da00a945489b2a681749eb56f5de00b900014e137ddae39f48f69d67') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.499 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'RAM_RESTRICTIONS' (with digest of '4e7bf348da00a945489b2a681749eb56f5de00b900014e137dd
ae39f48f69d67') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-RAM_RESTRICTIONS.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.503 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'GET_SENDER' (with digest of 'f0af56d2c5a48d60a4a5b5c903edfb7db3a736a94ed589d0b797df33ff9d3e1d') is enabled
 with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.505 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'GET_SENDER' (with digest of 'f0af56d2c5a48d60a4a5b5c903edfb7db3a736a94ed589d0b797df33f
f9d3e1d') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-GET_SENDER.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.509 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'FORWARD_SETCODE' (with digest of '2652f5f96006294109b3dd0bbde63693f55324af452b799ee137a81a905eed25') is en
abled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.510 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'FORWARD_SETCODE' (with digest of '2652f5f96006294109b3dd0bbde63693f55324af452b799ee137a81a905eed25') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-FORWARD_SETCODE.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.511 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER' (with digest of '8ba52fe7a3956c5cd3a656a3174b931d3bb2abb45578befc59f283ecd816a
405') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.514 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER' (with digest of '8ba52fe7a3956c5cd3a656a3174b931d3bb2abb45
578befc59f283ecd816a405') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.516 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'RESTRICT_ACTION_TO_SELF' (with digest of 'ad9e3d8f650687709fd68f4b90b41f7d825a365b02c23a636cef88ac2ac00c43') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.518 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'RESTRICT_ACTION_TO_SELF' (with digest of 'ad9e3d8f650687709fd68f4b90b41f7d825a365b02c23a636cef88ac2ac00c43') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-RESTRICT_ACTION_TO_SELF.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.519 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'DISALLOW_EMPTY_PRODUCER_SCHEDULE' (with digest of '68dcaa34c0517d19666e6b33add67351d8c5f69e999ca1e37931bc4
10a297428') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.520 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'DISALLOW_EMPTY_PRODUCER_SCHEDULE' (with digest of '68dcaa34c0517d19666e6b33add67351d8c5f69e999ca1e37931bc410a297428') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-DISALLOW_EMPTY_PRODUCER_SCHEDULE.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.521 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'FIX_LINKAUTH_RESTRICTION' (with digest of 'e0fb64b1085cc5538970158d05a009c24e276fb94e1a0bf6a528b48fbc4ff526') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.521 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'FIX_LINKAUTH_RESTRICTION' (with digest of 'e0fb64b1085cc5538970158d05a009c24e276fb94e1
a0bf6a528b48fbc4ff526') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-FIX_LINKAUTH_RESTRICTION.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.522 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'REPLACE_DEFERRED' (with digest of 'ef43112c6543b88db2283a2e077278c315ae2c84719a8b25f25cc88565fbea99') is e
nabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.526 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'REPLACE_DEFERRED' (with digest of 'ef43112c6543b88db2283a2e077278c315ae2c84719a8b25f25
cc88565fbea99') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-REPLACE_DEFERRED.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.527 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'NO_DUPLICATE_DEFERRED_ID' (with digest of '4a90c00d55454dc5b059055ca213579c6ea856967712a56017487886a4d4cc0
f') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.527 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'NO_DUPLICATE_DEFERRED_ID' (with digest of '4a90c00d55454dc5b059055ca213579c6ea85696771
2a56017487886a4d4cc0f') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-NO_DUPLICATE_DEFERRED_ID.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.527 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_LINK_TO_EXISTING_PERMISSION' (with digest of '1a99a59d87e06e09ec5b028a9cbb7749b4a5ad8819004365d02dc43
79a8b7241') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.527 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_LINK_TO_EXISTING_PERMISSION' (with digest of '1a99a59d87e06e09ec5b028a9cbb7749b4a
5ad8819004365d02dc4379a8b7241') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-ONLY_LINK_TO_EXISTING_PERMISSION.json
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.528 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:408          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'PREACTIVATE_FEATURE' (with digest of '0ec7e080177b2c02b278d5088611686b49d739925a92d9bfcacd7fc6b74053bd') i
s enabled without activation restrictions
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.528 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:505          operator()           ] Saved default specification for builtin protocol feature 'PREACTIVATE_FEATURE' (with digest of '0ec7e080177b2c02b278d5088611686b49d739925a92d9bf
cacd7fc6b74053bd') to: /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/protocol_features/BUILTIN-PREACTIVATE_FEATURE.json
warn  2019-11-25T08:17:47.528 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:873          plugin_initialize    ] Starting up fresh blockchain with default genesis state.
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.885 nodeos    main.cpp:93                   main                 ] nodeos version v1.8.6
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.885 nodeos    main.cpp:94                   main                 ] nodeos using configuration file /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.886 nodeos    main.cpp:95                   main                 ] nodeos data directory is /home/najam/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data
warn  2019-11-25T08:17:47.886 nodeos    controller.cpp:542            init                 ] No existing chain state or fork database. Initializing fresh blockchain state and resetting fork database.
warn  2019-11-25T08:17:47.887 nodeos    controller.cpp:432            initialize_blockchai ] Initializing new blockchain with genesis state
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.941 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:982          plugin_startup       ] starting chain in read/write mode
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.942 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:986          plugin_startup       ] Blockchain started; head block is #1, genesis timestamp is 2018-06-01T12:00:00.000
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.943 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:827       plugin_startup       ] producer plugin:  plugin_startup() begin
info  2019-11-25T08:17:47.944 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:862       plugin_startup       ] producer plugin:  plugin_startup() end
```

Comment: Is nodeos running? Verify by checking the blocks.log file or ps aux|grep nodeos

Answer (score 0):

You have somewhere an error in the genesis_start.sh or your port is used by another process. Whatever the reason is, you can get it from nodeos.log with `tail -f nodeos.log`. If your node is working properly on localhost however check his port and if it is different than 8888 your cleos command should look like

```
cleos -u http://localhost:"Your port here" create account eosio eosio.bpay EOS7s7TxBxXFijJ3C2fB6ZgLumQry5jH9Z1FiDuFu6x7AHiAWt5y5
```

Comment: nah my friend it was some copy paste issue. when you copy from official page and paste directly into vi or nando editor. it adds extra lines or maybe some hidden special characters. what i did is copy from docs paste into some gui editor making sure no extra empty lines between command arguments then paste into target vi or nano editor and boom issue solved. took me 3 days to realize this. i hate myself and you probably hating me too right now. forgive me friend. yours only *Anakin Skywalker*